# Moving EC2 Snapshots to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ebs

I have careated backup for my EBS volumes .
Now  I have 5 snapshot in EBS . for more safety I want to move snapshots to s3 bucket.

How to move move snapshots from EBS to S3 bucket. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation [about EBS snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html), you'll notice:

> You can back up the data on your EBS volumes to Amazon S3 by taking
>   point-in-time snapshots. Snapshots are incremental backups, which
>   means that only the blocks on the device that have changed after your
>   most recent snapshot are saved.
>
> [...]
>
> If you access a piece of data that hasn't been loaded yet, the volume
>   immediately downloads the requested data from Amazon S3, and then
>   continues loading the rest of the volume's data in the background.

So, the snapshots are automatically stored in S3, but you can't access them as a storage bucket key.

Comment: thank you .. it means automatically those are stored in S3... can we Download them in local machine??

Comment: No you can't download them.